# Python Networking Libraries

Tags: python, networking, libraries

I've search a little bit on net about urllib library in python 2.7, due to my friend's tip and because I've already used for a while. Well, what I really wanna know is about indications. Supposing I desire to create a application that is going to be used in a specific device that communicates with another device with same application, e.g A message application, or even a virtual simple game (using only the network), what are the possible libraries I can use? If some of you've already used anything to build a similar application, please, I'll appreciate your knowledge.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at ØMQ (ZeroMQ). It provides high performance, scalable async messaging without a broker (hence the Ø) and has a binding for Python (http://zeromq.org/bindings:python). For more info see http://zeromq.org/. There is a two part  intro to it at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-zeromq-from-source-on-a-centos-6-x64-vps and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-the-zeromq-messaging-library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to develop an application specific protocol which is different than [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

HTTP is carried over TCP and Python connects to TCP transports with the standard [socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). There is a small [overview of the use of sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) in the Python standard documentation.

The most important part of your new protocol is ensuring each side knows when the other side has sent a complete message. This can be very simple (each message ends with a newline) to as complex as you need.